# Online resources for entomology?

Tags: entomology, literature

I'm going to teach a c ollege-level introductory entomology course soon, and I'm looking for free online entomology resources. Does anyone have any recommendations?

In particular I'm looking for phylogenetic resources, experiment ideas, images, topics, etc.

Ideally, I'd love to find a discussion forum consisting of other entomology instructors sharing their ideas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The [Entomological Society of America](http://www.entsoc.org/) has dedicated page called [**Entomology Resources for Teachers**](http://www.entsoc.org/teachers), which might answer many of your questions. It compiles curated links to resources, universities,

Here are a couple of other entomological links/resources that I have saved from before:

- [Bugguide.net](http://bugguide.net)
  Pictures, simple keys and taxonomical info. Also has a forum.
- [The Entomological Foundation: Education](http://www.entfdn.org/education_links.php)
  Links, project ideas etc.
- [Kerbtier.de](http://www.kerbtier.de/enindex.html)
  Webpage on beetles found in Germny, but relevant for many European countries. Also has general pages on e.g. beetle morphology and a glossary that might be useful.